# Find the variance and mean squared error of $T=\max(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$

Tags: probability, mean-square-error

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be i.i.d. uniformly distributed on [$0, \theta$]. Consider the estimator $T=\max(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ of $\theta$. Determine the variance and mean square error of $T$.

My thoughts were the following:

For a uniform distributed random variable $X_i$, we know that the probability density function is
$$f_X(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}\ \ \ \text{for $x\in [0,\theta]$}$$ and that the cumulative distribution function is
$$F_X(x|\theta) = \frac{x}{\theta}\ \ \ \text{for $x\in [0, \theta$]}$$

Then for $T = \max{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n}$
$$F_T(t) = \mathbb{P}(\max(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)\leq t) =  \mathbb{P}(X_1\leq t)\mathbb{P}(X_2\leq t)...\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq t)$$
Therefore 
$$F_T(t) = \left(\frac{t}{\theta}\right)^n\ \ \ \ \text{for $0\leq t \leq \theta$}$$
From this I can calculate the probability density function $f_T(t)$ using
$$f_T(t) = F_T'(t)$$
I believe I can use this to calculate $\mathbb{E}[T]$ and $\mathbb{E}[T^2]$ and thus can calculate the variance. And then I have to calculate the bias in order to calculate the MSE(T)?
Am I doing this correctly? How do I calculate the bias?

Comment: Your approach looks good. Isn't the [bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_(statistics)) here just $\mathbb ET-\theta$?

Comment: Yes, except the the bias can be calculated directly from $\overline{T}=\mathbb{E}[T]$ as $\mbox{bias}_{\theta}=\overline{T}-\theta$

Comment: Note that $E[T^k] = \int_0^\infty k t^{k-1} (1-F_T(t)) dt$ for any non-negative random variable $T$. This may be a little bit less annoying than differentiating and then integrating.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/751229/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer but a hint (too long for a comment) concerning calculation.

Let $Y_i:=\frac{X_i}{\theta}$.

Then $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are iid uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ so we are dealing with a special case.

Let $S=\max(Y_1\dots Y_n)$ and find expectation and variance of $S$ on the way you suggest. In this calculation you are not bothered by the (annoying) parameter $\theta$. It makes the probability of making mistakes evidently smaller.

If done then based on $T=\theta S$ you can find $\mathbb ET=\theta\mathbb ES$, $\text{Var}T=\theta^2\text{Var}S$ or other things.

Personally I dislike parameters in calculations and try to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Some **Hints**:

- $\mathbb E[T]=\int_0^{\theta} n\cdot \left( \frac t\lambda \right)^n
     \, dt=\theta \frac{n}{n+1}$
- The bias is $\mathbb E[T]-\theta=\ldots$
- $\mathbb E[T^2]=\int_0^{\theta} t\cdot  n\cdot \left( \frac t\theta
     \right)^n \, dt= \theta ^2\frac{n}{n+2}$
- And the MSE of T is $\mathbb E((T-\theta)^2)$